# Django OneToOneField Error

Tags: django

My app allows users to create board and add pictures .

My aim is to try assoicate a board with a primary picture from it's picture list .I'll try my best to explain my situation.I'm trying display with every board  a main picture from it's picture list because when a user creates a board he can add pictures to his board and now I want to assoicate one of it's picture to display with the board.
I'l give you an example[image]

So I tried to assoicate the board with a primary picture by using the OneToOneField and I got this error 
pet_board.picture_id may not be NULL when I create a board

My models.py

```
class Board(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    picture = models.OneToOneField('Picture',related_name='picture',blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Picture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board ,related_name='lo')

    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

Comment: Is this how you link a picture to become a primary picture for a board

Comment: I think you have to create new field in the Picture model. For BooleanField that state if that picture is the primary then true, if not false. Don't change the picture to OnetoOneField because it will only store 1 picture per user

Comment: @catherine is  it possible to display a board with a primary key picture?

Comment: the main picture? yes just add another field for BooleanField

Comment: @catherine Okay so , how do I retrieve the main picture with the board?

Comment: I taught you before on how to create function inside model. Do that way. The picture must be equal to user and is_primary = True. Getch?

Comment: `Picture.objects.filter(board=self, is_primary=True)`. Put that under Board model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Board(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    picture = models.OneToOneField('Picture',related_name='picture',blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def primary_picture(self): 
        return Picture.objects.filter(board=self, is_primary=True)

    def ordinary_picture(self): 
        return Picture.objects.filter(board=self, is_primary=False)

class Picture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board ,related_name='lo')
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

{% for b in person.get_board %}  
    My Primary Pictures:
    {% for primary in b.primary_picture %}
        <img src="{{ primary.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}

    My Ordinary Pictures:
    {% for ord in b.ordinary_picture %}
        <img src="{{ ord.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yep     is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

Comment: it's working on me. What did you do? I copy my answer above then I add data in Picture model in the admin and it works. I check the is_primary then the picture is now primary.

Comment: Did your image dislay on template

Comment: yep, perfectly working. Sorry late reply, I having problem now and I can't concentrate answering in SO. I can't solve my problem in codes

Comment: Oh okay , Thank you for helping me . Your site is more important than this , so you can focus on that . :]

Comment: I can answer in SO but I just can't answer faster. I did not answer those questions needs time to think.

Comment: if I write functions in views.py does it make my site slower? than writing functions in modules

Comment: depends on how many data show in the page. If you want it in your view just try. Try to install debug toolbar so that you will know how many seconds your page load

Comment: There basic is just an hour. Every day I learn a lot (if I give time to study). I can learn fast if I want to so it depends on the person if this is really his passion

Comment: Codes is just like a game. You didn't know at first but when you try it you will learn it slowly.

Comment: Where the same ok. It's been 9months before I totally understand it. It's really hard to have self-study but it's worth because you can code alone.

Comment: I did not feel stress in Django even though there are times that it's hard to solve problem. What I feel is, it's a challenge so I didn't give up. I will do anything just to fix it until the last minute. Every time I solve problem, I'm really happy.

Comment: yeah I'm eating dinner now. And we are enjoying also because it's Kadayawan Festival

Comment: I don't know about that and I already see you on top of users. What is the limit for question?

Comment: I'm working now, at the same time answering SO. Just create another account temporary

Answer (score 2):

**models.py**

```
class Board(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Picture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    obj_board = Board.objects.get(user=request.user)
    obj_image = obj_board.picture_set.filter(is_primary=True)
    print obj_image.image.url  # output url in dev-server for tests
    # ... do something and return httpresponse
```